# how to use sqlite manager tables in eclipse for android

Tags: android

can anyone tell me step by step how to use sqlite manager tables in eclipse for android? because i am new on android and working on a university project.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Questoid CellObject SQLite & XML Browser](http://www.questoid.com/Download.aspx) plugin in Eclipse. Unfortunately, you have to register (for free) to download it.