# using sqlite manager in android application

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to view SQL database in Eclipse Debug mode for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333412/how-to-view-sql-database-in-eclipse-debug-mode-for-android)

I am developing an android application which involves data base,,,Fetching data from database

Can anyone tell the link of sqlite manager plugin download in android

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: It's duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333412/how-to-view-sql-database-in-eclipse-debug-mode-for-android/6333482#6333482

Comment: [How to view SQL database in Eclipse Debug mode for android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333412/how-to-view-sql-database-in-eclipse-debug-mode-for-android/6333482#6333482)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use an outside [program](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) to see the database. Once the database is created navigate to your app's data folder (/data/data/your.package/) and pull the database onto your machine. Then use this program to look at the data and run queries.

Comment: I second, I do that too with sqlitebrowser for linux

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite is native in android. You can start with many tutorial to build a database helper, such as [this one](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842).

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Stephane can u provide me the link where i can download sqlite manager plugin for eclipse,,,,I am not able to find the download link,,

Comment: Here is what you are looking for ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533340/how-to-use-sqlite-manager-tables-in-eclipse-for-android

Comment: It's also available from eclipse market place

Comment: snicolas can u provide me eclipse sqlite manager download market link,,plz if possible..